# Git: How to pull a new separate branch, without merging?

Tags: git

I cloned a git repository and started committing to a new branch in the new rep.
I now want to pull these changes into the original rep, but without merging with the original branch.
How can I do this?

Here's what I tried, in more detail:
I have repository A, with branch a, and cloned it into rep B.
I then created a new branch, b in rep B.
I did some commits in both A(a) and B(b), including changing the "same" file in both branches and deleting some files.
I now want to put everything in one repository, but keep branches a, b separate (not merge them).
i.e. when I checkout branch a, I want to see the files that were in A(a),
and when I checkout branch b, I want to see the files that were in B(b).

Here's what worked:
In Rep B, checkout branch a and pull branch a from rep A.
then throw away rep A and keep working with rep B, which has all the commits from both branches.

How could I achieve the same result, by pulling rep B into rep A?  The problem is that rep A does not have branch b.
When I tried the following, I got merge conflicts:
In rep A:

```
git checkout -b b
git pull B b
```

result:
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in x
CONFLICT (modify/delete): a deleted in 98e40aa69e149bfc315705a3661232389104fcc5 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of a left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

The content is as follows:
In branch a, I made changes in files a, x
In branch b, I deleted file a, and made changes in files b, x

Comment: After some more testing, I found out that I can pull the missing branch without conflicts if I create the branch at the same commit as it was made in repo B.  So:  use git log --oneline--decorate" to find which commit was used to create branch b.  Then checkout this commit in repoA and branch b there.  Then pull repoB without conflicts.  I was just expecting git to duplicate the branch at the right place for me.  Lesson for me:  When I want to start working on a new branch on cloned repository, create the new branch before the clone.  That makes it easier to pull the new branch back in.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fetch the branch from your new repo and check it out by a different name!

Steps: (After you have pushed a to RepoA and b to RepoB)

In repo B:

1. git fetch repoA a
2. git checkout -b a b

Comment: I don't want to modify repo B.  I already know how to do this.  I want to modify repo A.